# /bin/sh: parse long options using getopt, in the form --parameter='value'

Tags: shell, command-line, sh, getopt

I have following snippet to parse short and long options in `/bin/dash`.

The option `-n|--dry-run` takes no argument. But `--exclude` should take a string in the form of `--exclude='foo'`. To complicate matters further, `--exclude` has no short option.

The following code works when I use `script.sh --exclude`, but when I use `script.sh --exclude='foo'`, I get an error:

```
option '--exclude' doesn't allow an argument
```

here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

 OPTS=$(getopt --options 'n' --long 'exclude,dry-run' --name "$0" -- "$@")

 if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    printf "\n\033[1;31m Error:\033[0m Failed to parse options...exiting.\n\n"
    exit 1
 fi

 eval set -- "$OPTS"

 unset OPTS

# extract options and their arguments into variables.
 while true ; do
    case "$1" in

    --exclude )
        EXCLUDE="y"
        shift
        ;;

    -n | --dry-run )
        DRYRUN="y"
        shift
        ;;

    -- )
        shift
        break
        ;;

    *)
        printf "\n\033[1;31m Error:\033[0m Invalid option: \033[1;31m-$OPTARG\033[0m\n\n"
        exit 1
        ;;

    esac
 done


 echo \$\@ = $@
```

What do I have to change to be able to use `--exclude='foo'` ?

Comment: Note that relying on `getopt`, and _especially_ on the `util-linux` version of `getopt` (as the above does), makes your code not-so-POSIXy. If you want to work anywhere a standard-compliant `/bin/sh` is available, consider the practices described in [BashFAQ #35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) instead.

Comment: To quote that FAQ: "Never use getopt(1). Traditional versions of getopt cannot handle empty argument strings, or arguments with embedded whitespace. There is a version of getopt(1) in util-linux, but you should not use it. Why not? Because you would need to write special safety-checking code to ensure that you've actually got this nonstandard getopt, and then you would still need to write a fallback option processor for when you don't have it. So you're doing twice as much work and getting no significant benefits for it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that `--exclude` can take an argument by appending a `:` to the name.

```
OPTS=$(getopt --options 'n' --long 'exclude:,dry-run' --name "$0" -- "$@")
```

From the man page:

> -l, --longoptions *longopts*
>
> The long (multi-character) options to be recognized.  More
> than one option name may be specified at once, by
> separating the names with commas.  This option may be
> given more than once, the longopts are cumulative.  **Each
> long option name in longopts may be followed by one colon
> to indicate it has a required argument,** and by two colons
> to indicate it has an optional argument.